# Error trying to dynamically delete a row from a sql server ce database using WebMatrix

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I am trying to delete an old row from a sql-server-ce database (based on the primary key value), whenever that primary key value is updated.

The goal is to (once supplied with the new id) add a new entry with an insert statement and then delete the old entry. It might be important to know that the data type for the primary key (City Tag Number) within the database itself is int, and the C# variable originalCTag was declared var, but assigned "" (empty string) upon its declaration, and then assigned the string representation of the desired target primary key value.

While this should be a simple task, here's the question:

Why is the sql action query not working? Using C# in WebMatrix, here is what I have tried:

```
db.Execute("DELETE FROM Vaccinations WHERE [City Tag Number] = " + originalCTag);
```

^This states that there was an error parsing the query at the index of the equals sign.

```
db.Execute("DELETE FROM Vaccinations WHERE [City Tag Number] = @0", originalCTag);
```

^This states that the input string was not in the correct format.

```
db.Execute("DELETE FROM Vaccinations WHERE [City Tag Number] = @0", int.Parse(originalCTag));
```

^This states that the input string was not in the correct format.

```
db.Execute("DELETE FROM Vaccinations WHERE [City Tag Number] = @0", originalCTag.ToString());
```

^This (once again) states that the input string was not in the correct format (can we not parameterize queries with a DELETE statement)?

So... lastly, I tried:

```
db.Execute("DELETE FROM Vaccinations WHERE [City Tag Number] = '" + originalCTag + "'");
```

^This doesn't produce any errors, but also does not do what it's supposed to (e.g., delete the row).

At this point, I'm kind of at a loss. I would expect at least one of these statements to perform the desired function, if not a few of them.

Clearly I am missing something (and I wouldn't be surprised if that something was obvious) here. If any of these statements 'should work' then maybe there is something else wrong with my code before the db.Execute statement.

-------------------UPDATE-----------------
In case you want to see the db declaration statement:

```
var db = Database.Open("Vaccinations");
```

Yes, Vaccinations is the name of the database and the (only) table within that database.

Comment: VoidKing I think it might help to post the Method where this code resides if it's not posting an error, the issue could be that you are not doing proper Error Handling.. please show how you are connecting to the DB it will others to understand where you may have made errors also try to change your Query When Doing Inserts you should use Parametrized query's as well @0 is that a Parameter in the DB if now then you need to use @Paramater Names that will utilize the Parameters.AddWithValues() method...

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for trying to help, but I have several db.Execute and db.Query statements in this site (one directly above the attempted DELETE statement here) so I know the connection is fine. Also, I am not trying to do an insert statement, and if you read my examples you will see that I tried to use parameterized queries more than once.

Comment: I meant to write Delete instead of Insert..but there is a difference between using Execute Query which is normally used for Select statements vs ExecuteNonQuery..

Comment: Your attempt to use Parameterized Query is actually incorrect..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Actually, the code shows a valid parameterised query using the ASP.NET Web Pages Database Helper.

Comment: Exactly.. that's what I said.. I am going to post a working example for him to follow.. this will work for him also Delete Command requires db.ExecuteNonQuery() command..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Your previous comment appears to say that VoidKing's parameter query is **NOT** correct. I'm saying it is. By the way, ADO.NET is not used directly in the Web Pages framework. Data Access is largely undertaken via the Database helper:

Comment: I can't tell based on his examples but .. using the code that I have posted I use this all the time in ASP.NET and so do lots of other developers on this site.. in regards to how to setup Database Connections and Query Execution.. he has to be willing to try..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined error messages say that the value held by originalCTag is not a number. It is most likely still an empty string since that is what you say you first assigned it to. You should check that the code that you use to assign it a valid value does what you think it does.

Comment: Once again, you are right. I realize that what the problem was will just make me sound dumber, but, I was declaring the variable string originalCTag = "" at the beginning of the page, while only assigning it the actual value I wanted in an (!IsPost) branch (dumb, as after the post it resets it to empty string and since it is a post, is never reassigned). Sry about that.

Answer (score 0):

VoidKing this is how you should be doing / building your Parameterized Queries as I have asked you earlier if you can paste the Method of one section in your code where you are trying to do the Delete.. I hope this example can help you in regards to how you should setup your query's .. also notice how I have used the `ExecuteNonQuery` vs Execute

```
using (SqlCeConnection sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection("Your ConnectionString"))
{
  sqlConn.Open();

  using (SqlCeCommand sqlComm = new SqlCeCommand("Vaccinations WHERE [City Tag Number] = (@CityTagNumber)", sqlConn))
  {
    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityTagNumber", originalCTag);
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: I advise you read up on the ASP.NET Web Pages Framework - particularly data access: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: Mike is that a suggestion to me or to the OP..? and I am well aware of the many different ways to access Database whether it's asp.net or C# winforms, webservices, window services, wcf ect...

Comment: It is a suggestion aimed at you. The OP already knows about the Database Helper. You don't seem to know anything about it, or the Web Pages framework.

Comment: LOL Mike.. I think that if you are not aware of database connectivity regardless if it's helper or not.. and if you think that there's only one way to connect to a database.. then I think that you don't seem to know anything about web pages and it's .NET Framework btw..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Again, I appreciate your help, but I don't think Mike is trying to say that there is only one way to connect to a database, he's saying that just because the way I did it wasn't the way you do it, doesn't make it a syntax error (or any other for that matter). That having been said, I appreciate the example you've shown and will try look at this ExecuteNonQuery method, but if you are familiar with Webmatrix, this seems redundant because you select query with db.Query (or QuerySingle/QueryValue depending on your expected results) and insert/update/delete with db.Execute, anyway

Comment: VoidKing all I am saying is there is more than 1 way to skin a cat and we are all here to offer help not to put others down.. do Mike's comments are not warranted here and I truly don't appreciate his cantankerous attitude..that being said.. happy new year and happy coding

Comment: @DJKRAZE, I hope you have a great new year, as well, Sir, and I can clearly tell that you know your share of how to code, but Mike Brind has helped me on countless occasions, both directly (here) and indirectly (his website/his book, both of which are great examples of brevity and concise but thorough deliverance), so I know Mike knows what he's talking about when it comes to WebMatrix, C#, and especially ASP.NET.

Comment: noted.. and all I am saying is his tack / comments were a bit unprofessional in nature.. have safe new years

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not to try and have a lengthy discussion or anything, but when I first signed up here, I found Mike a little cantankerous, too, but after realizing that he wasn't just some average over-egotistical coder, I honestly felt like, maybe he did deserve my respect. After that, I sort of just started listening (not saying you need follow some out-of-context example of mine or anything, just saying what happened to me), and I learned a very great deal from him in exchange. Now, if he advises me to do something, I usually just think (even if it sounds abrupt) "Yeah, you're probably right."

Comment: there are others on this site whom have authored C# Books for Example Jon Skeet one of the many that I respect and quite frankly he's a great example on how to respond to users whom are not as seasoned I've never had any ignorant comments from him nor other developers who offer other ways of looking at simple or complex problems.. that's why we have this site.. for others to learn from one another.. I respect your choice to deal with Mike but I stand by my earlier statement about his approach.. it's just my opinion not trying to start any text wars here... take care

Comment: @DJKRAZE That's cool, as I'm sure I'm probably not as good at this as Mike, Mr. Skeet, or you, too, All I can say is that I don't think Mike is trying to be rude or even being rude at all. He's just concise and to the point, but that's what makes his writings so easy to read, yet very knowledge rewarding. I love this site and the community both for their help and their professional nature. May they both survive for as long as technology will continue to advance. Have a wonderful 2013 for any who read this, and thanks!

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't believe any of my comments have been unprofessional, but if you have been offended by any of them, that was certainly not my intention.